# creating automatic scrollbar in php

Tags: scrollbar

I am doing image cropping in my webpage.My problem is that when i crop a large image which is larger than the container holding the image,scroll bar is not automatically coming.So i am unable to crop the large image whose remaining part is under the container which is not visible to the user.So is there any way to create automatic scroll bar.thanks in advance.

Comment: I've removed the "PHP" tag, as PHP doesn't know the concept of a scrollbar. What you're looking for is probably a solution with HTML and CSS. Would you mind sharing some code you use to display the image?

Comment: @BerryLangerak i only found it because of that PHP tag ><

Comment: @VBAssassin .It is working with all other browsers.The problem is with IE6 and IE8

Comment: @viks Like VBAssassin mentioned, you're probably helped with using "overflow: auto;" in CSS. Nevertheless, this is hard to answer without having code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the css overflow property

```
<div style='overflow:auto;width:300px;height:300px;'>
    <img src='image.png' width='1000' height='1000' />
</div>
```

Which will load an image 1000x1000 pixels, but a scrollable area of just 300 x 300 pixels.

Other possible values of overflow are: visible, hidden, scroll, auto, inherit

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: @BerryLangerak Thanks for your reply.It is working with all other browsers.The problem is with IE6 and IE8

Comment: @Berry Langerak If you give me your mail id,I wil send that code.

Comment: Ah, you never specified that! First of all, IE6 is no longer supported and you really shouldn't need to worry about IE6: http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: An this might help your IE8 problem: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/ (p.s. remember to set your doctype)